# Why getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getAbsolutePath()) throws nullPointerException?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, inputstream, filechooser

After I've searched for a solution for my problem & reading similar questions which are very more professional than mine,... well, I hope you pay attention to my problem, even though it seems simple!
I'm working on a project which open files by FileChooser, then I'm trying to show it on a pane. The problem is getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getAbsolutePath()) returns null.So while I can print the path & see it's true, but I cannot use it in creating images. Part of my code is:

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

...

```
     Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

The exception is:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null ...
```

I work on Ubuntu by NetBeans.
I really appretiate helps. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the whole exception message if you want a solution, that would make it easier

Comment: The argument to getResourceAsStream is not a file path.  Use `new Image(file.toURI().toString())` to read a file.

Comment: @VGR Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageIO:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(file);
```

`getResourceAsStream` requires a path on the class path. As the resource could be in a jar, its full URI would be `jar:file:/..../xyz.jar!/...`. And `File` is on the file system.

One cannot mix those, only `Path` is a new generalisation allowing paths in several "file" systems.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use file systems. Actually I want to fix this problem & after that expend the class for every type of files. For now, I want to see if I can do sth like photoshop does.

Comment: To be clear: the above works with your FileChooser, picking a File on the phyisical disk. And ImageIO can also read from any InputStream, not just File.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read about it more & more to understand better what you've taught me.